# Will TCP/IP socket program work with ZigBee?

Tags: tcp, zigbee

I have a TCP/IP Socket program created using .NET running on Raspberry Pi.

Is it possible that this program without any modification will expose the socket endpoint on a `ZegBee Network`, not on a WiFi or an Ethernet network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I asked may be possible because ZigBee for not fall under the ISO/OSI 7 layers' TCP/IP communication stacks.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, for now closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your post if you require just ZigBee networking, or want a profile such as ZigBee HomeAutomation.

If you just want a ZigBee network then you can take a look a this:
https://git.ti.com/znp-host-framework/znp-host-framework
http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDC-ZNP-HOST-SW3

It is a simple SW component that connects to a ZigBee Network Processor and allows you to start/connect to a ZigBee network and send/receive messages.

If you require Home Automation Profile then take a look at the free Z-STACK-LINUX-GATEWAY download from here:
http://www.ti.com/tool/z-stack

This is more involved and complicated to setup than above, but you get a Home Automation API rather than a ZigBee Network API. It is a Linux based ZigBee Home Automation gateway that offers a ZigBee API (via protobuf) over a TCP IP socket. The documentation shows it running on a beaglebone black, this is similar to a Raspberry Pi so it should not be an issue porting it.

The Z-STACK-LINUX-GATEWAY is a "Gateway" between ZigBee Home Automation and TCP/IP and can receive on/off messages from a switch, or it can send on/off messages to a light, or it can send a bind to connect a ZigBee switch to a ZigBee light. The Light/Switch is just one example, there are many other device/message types in ZigBee. Typically ZigBee Gateways are Coordinators, as such the Z-STACK-LINUX-GATEWAY is a Coordinator by default, it can be configured as an Router/EndDevice, but then you will need to find some other device to fulfill the role of a Coordinator (as this is required to start and join a ZigBee network).

Regards,
Tony.

Comment: I think, what I want to be able to comprehend and do is to without modifying my TCP/IP socket program, I need to utilize the ZigBee network, keeping my program abstracted from knowing what's ZigBee. Is it possible ??? E.g. this socket programmming does not worry about underlying Ethernet or WiFi, right, is this possible with ZigBee as well ??

Comment: If you created a Socket/network device where the underlying protocol was ZigBee then where should it send/receive that data to/from on the ZigBee network? i.e. What device on the network should the data be sent to and how do you map the TCP/IP port/address to a ZigBee endpoint/network address? Maybe a better option would be to use 6LowPan, which has IPv6 addressable nodes on the 2.4G/Sub1G RF network, if this is an option you could take a look at http://www.contiki-os.org/index.html.